# Is there any way how to hard reset FTDI chip using libftdi or libusb?

Tags: usb, reset, ftdi

I need to reset FT2232H in order to regain MPSSE output after switching into FT245 SYNC FIFO, but using **ftdi_usb_reset()** (on both channel A and channel B) I cannot get back into MPSSE after FT245 was enabled and only way to regain access to MPSSE is to unplug and replug USB from FTDI.

But I need to do it in software, because from time to time my design in FPGA gets stuck and since debugging all stucks in FPGA is tedious and not guaranteed that I'll find all stucks, I need MPSSE to access reset pin of FPGA and unplugging device is not very convenient.

This is also needed for firmware updates, I need MPSSE to put FPGA to Hi-Z to access SPI flash with bitstream and it is inconvenient for user to replug USB device before updating FW.

Is there any libftdi or libusb way to, ideally reset POWER of USB device?

Comment: I know this an old question but if you haven't found a solution I was wondering if you could provide which OS you are using. I could try to find out what fpga is and which platform it runs on but that would be work on my part and wouldn't guarantee a definite answer.